# Manually calling a class based generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I'm currently trying to call a class based Generic view from within another class based generic view and cant seem to do it correctly.

Ways I've tried:

```
result = CategoryTypes.as_view()  # The same way you put it in the urlconf
print result
```

Prints: `<function CategoryTypes at 0x92bd924>`

```
CategoryTypes.as_view()(self.request)
# &
CategoryTypes().dispatch(self.request)
```

Tracebacks:

`ContentNotRenderedError at /crm/categories/company/ The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.`

```
result = CategoryTypes().__init__()
print result
```

Prints: `None`

How do I call this from another view? I've seriously tried every method in the class and way of calling it I can think of.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first way -- `CategoryTypes.as_view()(self.request)` -- is right. The problem is that if your view returns a `TemplateResponse`, its `render` method isn't called automatically.

So if you need to access the content of the response, call `render()` on it first.

Comment: This is the exact behavior I'm seeing.  I don't call render on the response object when the view is called from the web server, so what's the difference when calling it manually that makes it necessary?

Comment: @TimSaylor From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/), `TemplateResponse` is meant to allow decorators and middleware to modify the response before it's rendered (e.g. changing the template and context), so it's not rendered until later (details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#the-rendering-process))

Comment: @TimSaylor In particular, rendering happens here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L134-139

Answer (score 1):

Or you can directly access just content via `result.rendered_content`. Before making this be sure you will set session into your request before passing into a view:

```
self.request.session = {}
CategoryTypes.as_view()(self.request)
```